# How to embed SQL script in Azure Data Factory Mapping Data Flows Expression Builder

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-mapping-data-flow

After executing my mapping dataflow I would like to run a clean-up script using the Post SQL Script option of the Sink activity.

[image]

However I'm not having much success with the expression builder.
This is what I've tried so far:

```
concat ( 'UPDATE [cfg].[Entity] SET SchemaVersion =' , toString(CachedEntities#lookup($EntityName).EntityID + 1) )
```

Comment: is SchemaVersion a string column or numeric?

Comment: Custom expression should be an array of strings not string. Wrap your expression in square brackets and see if that fixes the issue.

[concat ( 'UPDATE [cfg].[Entity] SET SchemaVersion =' , toString(CachedEntities#lookup($EntityName).EntityID + 1) )]

Comment: The error was in the syntax. It works this way:
toString(CachedEntities#lookup($EntityName).SchemaVersion + 1)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @user1309226 for updating the error cause and resolution in the comments. Posting it as an answer to help other community members.

This syntax worked: `toString(CachedEntities#lookup($EntityName).SchemaVersion + 1)`

[image]